# what is the difference between runtime and speed of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

I am reading a book that implies they are different. According to the book Big O tells how the speed of an algorithm relates to the number of items, but it does to refer to the running time of an algorithm for a given number of items. 
I don't understand the difference.

Comment: What is the book? Can you post the specific passage that you're referring to? (I think I know what the authors have in mind, and if so, it's not actually a difference between "runtime" and "speed"; but without seeing the passage, I can't be sure.)

Comment: Well, runtime part is defined by omitted in O notation constant(s). F.e. algorithm A with runtime 1000sec*n and algoithm B with runtime 1sec*n are both belonging to O(n) class, but runtime is clearly quite different

Answer (score 0):

Big 'O' is how the algorithm's runtime scales with the number of inputs

Building  pyramids is O(n) it has a slow runtime but scales linearly with the number of pyramids.

Sorting the names of pyramids you have built into alphabetical order is O(n log n) it is 'slower' than building them but in practice the runtime of the algorithm is probably quicker. Unless you have a large number of pyramids.